# Conmutator Subgroups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

How can I show that if $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ then $H'$ is a subgroup of $G'$ where $H'$ and $G'$ are the conmutator subgroups of $H$ and $G$ respectively. Any hints or suggestions will be welcomed! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Commutators of elements of $H$ are a fortiori commutators of elements of $G$, and inclusion of generators passes to the generated subgroups.